# Every Rails command fails epically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I recently ran into a problem and in desperation decided to uninstall and reinstall both Ruby and Rails on my OS X 10.6. I've reinstalled Ruby and gem installed rails. Now, though, I get this error or similar EVERY time I try to run a rails command (even -v):

```
       rails -v
    /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
        from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
        from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
        from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p1

25@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
    from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
    from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
    from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

ANy ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Assuming that you're running that from your app directory, what do you see when you run `bundle install`? Is there an output line containing `bcrypt-ruby`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to install [bcrypt-ruby](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby)

Maybe try `sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby`?

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle install` then run `bundle exec rails -v` see if this clears the issue.